# Transmuting `bool` to `u8`

Tags: rust

The following code works correctly with Rust 1.8 on amd64.

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let f: u8 = unsafe { mem::transmute(false) };
    let t: u8 = unsafe { mem::transmute(true) };
    assert_eq!(0, f);
    assert_eq!(1, t);
}
```

My question is, can I assume that this will always works? I tried to find a reference about `bool` representation, but I only found [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/b49e9fa794addc197e58743bdc120cb9740b73c0) and [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14608), but I think that is not authoritative.

Comment: Why would you do this? (Insert melodramatic gasps.)

Comment: To create a compact option type for bool, similar to https://github.com/llogiq/optional. The optional crate uses an enumeration, but that do not allow to return a reference to the inner value.

Comment: Don't see any functional difference against something like `let f: u8 = if boolValue { 1u8 } else { 0u8 }` (not sure about the exact rust syntax). But the version without transmute will work without relying on any compiler behavior.

Comment: I need the transmute  for the purpose I described in the other comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was never any RFC adopted defining the representation of `bool`.  That said, as a practical matter it's very unlikely it will change.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46156

Answer (score 6):

**Update as of 2021**: [The Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/boolean.html) now defines the memory representation for `bool` as a 1-byte value equal to either 0 or 1:

> An object with the boolean type has a size and alignment of 1 each. The value false has the bit pattern `0x00` and the value true has the bit pattern `0x01`. It is undefined behavior for an object with the boolean type to have any other bit pattern.

Comment: > Finally, this book is not normative. It may include details that are specific to rustc itself, and should not be taken as a specification for the Rust language. Specially, https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/pull/940, have been write by a collaborator not a language core team so I wouldn't use it as reference.

Comment: @Stargateur Rust has no normative spec afaik. If this page of the reference book is not intended to define the memory representation of bool, I think we should file a documentation bug as this page states a representation pretty authoritatively.

Comment: @Stargateur Also, according to that pull request, the allowed values for bool were already specified in `src/behavior-considered-undefined.md`... (see first file in Files Changed tab)

Answer (score 4):

The bool representation seems to be very strict. It is represented as 1 and 0, but I'd like to caution that if for some insane reason this changes you'll get some strange behavior if you blindly assume that `true == <some u8 that isn't what Rust really uses>`. This is the opposite direction to your question, but I think it makes a point:

```
fn main() {
    use std::mem;

    let b: bool = unsafe {mem::transmute(4 as u8)};

    println!("{} {} {}", b, b == true, b == false);

    if b {
        println!("evaluates true");
    }

    if !b {
        println!("evaluates false");
    }

    let x: u8 = unsafe{mem::transmute(b)};

    println!("{}", x);

    let x = b as u8;

    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This produces a different output on nearly every configuration on that Playground I tested it on. With frequent flat out contradictions within the same program:

### Debug/Stable:

```
true true true
evaluates false
0
0
```

This means it prints as true, compares as true with both true and false, but evaluates  in a branch as false. And transmutes back to 0.

### Release/Stable:

```
true false true
evaluates true
4
4
```

This is probably what you'd "expect" if you were using a C-style bool, and has the correct transmute behavior. (Edit: actually, no it's not. It prints wrong! It compares the opposite to how it evaluates).

### Debug/Beta:

```
true true true
evaluates false
4
4
```

Same as Debug/Stable, but transmutes back correctly (I assume this was probably a bug that got fixed).

### Release/Beta:

Same as Release/Stable

### Debug/Nightly:

Same as Debug/Beta

### Release/Nightly:

Same as Release for others.

### Bonus

If you change `println!("{} {} {}", b, b == true, b == false);` to `println!("{} {}", b, b == true);` you get different printing behavior.

For instance, on Debug/Stable:

```
true false
evaluates false
0
0
```

In addition, transmuting from `1 as u8` works as expected on all configurations, so it's not solely a `transmute` issue.

---

The moral of the story is that, while this is unlikely to change, you potentially have one hell of a Heisenbug on your hands if it does (or you  make a mistake with the u8 and transmute it back or change it with an unsafe pointer). For most cases, I'd probably just stick with the perfectly working and safe `my_bool as u8`, though I understand your use case may prohibit this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you sad, this is the opposite direction of my question.  Anyway, it was a interesting answers.