# Is bool guaranteed to be 1 byte?

Tags: size, rust, primitive-types

The [Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#primitive-types) is vague on `bool`'s size.
Is it guaranteed to be 1 byte, or is it unspecified like in C++?

```
fn main() {
    use std::mem;
    println!("{}",mem::size_of::<bool>()); //always 1?
}
```

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/36924530/5189607

Comment: See also [What is the correct type for returning a C99 `bool` to Rust via the FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47705093/155423).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rust emits `i1` to LLVM for `bool` and relies on whatever it produces. LLVM uses `i8` (one byte) to represent `i1` in memory for all the platforms supported by Rust for now. On the other hand, there's no certainty about the future, since the Rust developers have been refusing to commit to the particular `bool` representation so far.

So, it's guaranteed by the current implementation but not guaranteed by any specifications.

You can find more details in [this RFC discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/954) and the linked PR and issue.

Please, see [E_net4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286603) for more information about changes introduced in Rust since this answer had been published.

Comment: In particular [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/954#issuecomment-83811006) which explicitly states that they don't want to tie down the representation.

Answer (score 19):

While historically there was a wish to avoid committing to a more specific representation, it was eventually [decided in January 2018](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46176#issuecomment-359593446) that `bool` should provide the following guarantees:

- The definition of `bool` is equivalent to the C99 definition of `_Bool`

  - In turn, for all currently supported platforms, the size of `bool` is exactly 1.

The documentation has been updated accordingly. In the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/boolean.html), `bool` is defined as thus:

> The `bool` type is a datatype which can be either `true` or `false`. The boolean type uses one byte of memory. [...]

It has also been documented since 1.25.0 that the output of [`std::mem::size_of::<bool>()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) is 1.

As such, one can indeed rely on `bool` being 1 byte (and if this is ever to change, it will be a pretty loud change).

See also:

- [In C how much space does a bool (boolean) take up? Is it 1 bit, 1 byte or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8014161/155423)
- [Why is a boolean 1 byte and not 1 bit of size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4626815/155423) (C++)