# What is the correct type for returning a C99 `bool` to Rust via the FFI?

Tags: type-conversion, rust, boolean, ffi

A colleague and I have been scratching our heads over how to return a `bool` from `<stdbool.h>` (a.k.a. `_Bool`) back to Rust via the FFI.

We have our C99 code we want to use from Rust:

```c
bool
myfunc(void) {
   ...
}
```

We let Rust know about `myfunc` using an `extern C` block:

```
extern "C" {
    fn myfunc() -> T;
}
```

What concrete type should `T` be?

Rust doesn't have a `c_bool` in the `libc` crate, and if you search the internet, you will find various GitHub issues and RFCs where people discuss this, but don't really come to any consensus as to what is both correct and portable:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1982#issuecomment-297534238
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/14608
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/992
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46156

As far as I can gather:

- The size of a `bool` in C99 is undefined other than the fact it must be at least large enough to store `true` (1) and `false` (0). In other words, at least one bit long.
- It could even be [one bit wide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1982#issuecomment-297531453).
- Its size might be [ABI defined](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1982#issuecomment-297942544).

[This comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1982#issuecomment-297534238) suggests that if a C99 `bool` is passed into a function as a parameter or out of a function as the return value, *and* the `bool` is smaller than a C `int` then it is promoted to the same size as an `int`. Under this scenario, we can tell Rust `T` is `u32`.

All right, but what if (for some reason) a C99 `bool` is 64 bits wide? Is `u32` still safe? Perhaps under this scenario we truncate the 4 most significant bytes, which would be fine, since the 4 least significant bytes are more than enough to represent `true` and `false`.

Is my reasoning correct? Until Rust gets a `libc::c_bool`, what would you use for `T` and why is it safe and portable for all possible sizes of a C99 `bool` (>=1 bit)?

Comment: *Under this scenario, we can tell Rust `T` is `u32`* — no, you can't as the same problem occurs: [C doesn't define the size of an `int` other than as a minimum of 16 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/155423).

Comment: There have to be at least `CHAR_BIT` bits in a `bool`, so at least 8 (since `CHAR_BIT >= 8`). The footnote in the link is saying that the *width* of `bool`, a term which is defined as excluding padding bits, may be 1.

Comment: Shepmaster: oops, I meant to say 'c_int'   not 'u32'. Would this work?

Comment: @EddBarrett It'd certainly be *better*, AFAICT, but the 64-bit-possibility is still worrisome.

Comment: Shepmaster: Hrm. I think what i'm taking away from this is that the problem only exists when a C99 bool is larger than 'T'. So following on from that, shouldnt using the smallest unsigned Rust integer type be safe, i.e. u8? If the C bool is larger, we truncate. If it is smaller, e.g. 1 bit, presumably this would have to be extended to the smallest integer a memory cell or register can address: a byte, which is in line with u8. Any holes in that reasoning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of [2018-02-01](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46176#issuecomment-362351652), the size of Rust's bool is [officially the same as C's `_Bool`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46176#issuecomment-359593446).

This means that `bool` is the correct type to use in FFI.

---

**The rest of this answer applies to versions of Rust before the official decision was made**

> Until Rust gets a `libc::c_bool`, what would you use for `T` and why is it safe and portable for all possible sizes of a C99 bool (>=1 bit)?

As you've already linked to, the *official* answer is still "to be determined". That means that the only possibility that is guaranteed to be correct is: **nothing**.

That's right, as sad as it may be. The only truly safe thing would be to convert your `bool` to a known, fixed-size integral type, such as `u8`, for the purpose of FFI. That means you need to marshal it on both sides.

---

Practically, I'd keep using `bool` in my FFI code. As people have pointed out, it magically lines up on all the platforms that are in wide use at the moment. If the language decides to make `bool` FFI compatible, you are good to go. If they decide something else, I'd be *highly* surprised if they didn't introduce a lint to allow us to catch the errors quickly.

See also:

- [Is bool guaranteed to be 1 byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38047167/155423)

Comment: I would note that for the purpose of FFI it may be of interest to restrict oneself to C89, which is significantly more standard than C99. There's little gain to using C99, so one might as well get that extra edge in portability. In C89, the usual convention is to use `int` (or `libc::c_int` in Rust) as a return type, with `0` signifying success and a negative value signifying an error.

Comment: We ended up using an `int` since this is well-defined in both languages.

Comment: Sorry shepmaster, a moderator moved my edit into your answer.

Comment: Wait! It was you!

Comment: @EddBarrett not a moderator, [it was me](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47705093/revisions) [and me](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47705543/revisions).

Comment: @EddBarrett answers don't belong in questions. By having answers in questions, it breaks the ability to upvote and downvote them separately. It also dis-incentivizes people from providing answers because why would you ever upvote an answer if the answer is in the question? If you'd like, you can also edit your answer below to reflect the current state of affairs.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thought, I'm going to try answering my own question. Please comment if you can find a hole in the following reasoning.

**This is not the correct answer -- see the comments below**

I think a Rust `u8` is always safe for `T`.

We know that a C99 `bool` is an integer large enough to store 0 or 1, which means it's free to be an unsigned integer of at least 1-bit, or (if you are feeling weird) a signed integer of at least 2-bits.

Let's break it down by case:

1. If the C99 `bool` is 8-bits then a Rust `u8` is perfect. Even in the signed case, the top bit will be a zero since representing 0 and 1 never requires a negative power of two.
2. If the C99 `bool` is larger than a Rust `u8`, then by "casting it down" to a 8-bit size, we only ever discard leading zeros. Thus this is safe too.
3. Now consider the case where the C99 `bool` is smaller than the Rust `u8`. When returning a value from a C function, it's not possible to return a value of size less than one byte due to the underlying calling convention. The CC will require return value to be loaded into a register or into a location on the stack. Since the smallest register or memory location is one byte, the return value will need to be extended (with zeros) to at least a one byte sized value (and I believe the same is true of function arguments, which too must adhere to calling convention). If the value is extended to a one-byte value, then it's the same as case 1. If the value is extended to a larger size, then it's the same as case 2.

Comment: You're making assumptions about representation and calling conventions that may not hold for all platforms supported by C and Rust. For example, if return values are passed on the stack instead of by register, you could end up grabbing the *top* byte of the return value instead of the bottom. `u8` is *extremely likely* to work (given the platforms supported by both languages), but it's no more a guarantee than just using `bool`.